# Trying to parse a complex boolean expression in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse a string that is in the following format:

```
boolean1 && boolean2 &&..... booleank
```

or

```
boolean1 || boolean3 || .... booleank
```

When || and && can appear between each boolean value (which is in String, i have my own test to see if that string can be a boolean), into this:
String[] array = {boolean1,boolean2,....booleank}
All my data comes in a string and my code (which doesn't work like expected yet) is this:

```
String line = "a || b && c"; //Just an example to test
    String[] booleans = line.split("[||,&&]*");
    for(String x: booleans){
        x = x.replaceall("\\s*","");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

This doesn't work as expected..
I want it to print:
a
b
c

Output I recevie:

[image]

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: imho you should rename `booleans` to `literals`, unless each `booleans[i]` is either `"true"` or `"false"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
\s*(&&|\|\|)\s*
```

Usage:

```
String line = "a || b && c"; //Just an example to test
String[] booleans = line.split("\\s*(&&|\\|\\|)\\s*");
for(String x: booleans) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

It will also remove the whitespaces, so the line below should not be needed:

```
x = x.replaceall("\\s*", "");
```

[Try the Java code online](https://ideone.com/4gOvKj)

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. can you explain why (&&|\\|\\|) is what you put inside?

Comment: OK i understand it. thanks

Comment: @Eyzuky I'm happy that I could help you. Glad to see you have follow up questions and you can answer them yourself, that means something is sticking ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the array, you could do this:

```
String line = "a || b && c"; //Just an example to test
String newLine = line.replaceAll("(\\|\\|)|&&", "");

System.out.println("Line:    " + line);
System.out.println("newLine: " + newLine);
```

Output:

```
Line:    a || b && c
newLine: a b c
```

Otherwise, the selected answer removes all white space hence the `\s*`

```
String line = "a || b && c"; //Just an example to test
String newLine = line.replaceAll("\\s*(&&|\\|\\|)\\s*", "");

System.out.println("Line:    " + line);
System.out.println("newLine: " + newLine);
```

Output:

```
Line:    a || b && c
newLine: abc
```